# Facebook like a different domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

OK, I have the standard Facebook Like code.

But we are ajaxing in Tumblr posts from the Tumblr feed and putting the FB Like button in.

So we are LIKING the Tumblr post URL.

However the page is not on a Tumbler URL, so FB momentarilly shows the comments box, then replaces it with a Confirm button, which triggers a popup.  Like in the popup, then it allows you to use the normal JS comment that should appear on the button.

QA and UI have flagged this up as unacceptable, so is this a massive UI failing by FB? Whatever it is, and how can I get around it?

If we LIKE a unique URL on our site/domain this works as intended;
BUT THEN we would have to write a backend to receive that URL and present OG tags for FB to scrape, probably grabbing from the tumblr post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default the Like plugin it will search the page for og:metadata,
to go forward you can use the new build in, Open Graph Like Action
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/

So, now you can associate each Open Graph object with a like.